# How do you keep track of the details for the different websites you maintain?

Tags: freelance-websites, project-management

I have multiple websites, mainly in Wordpress, that I manage and I need to share the details of those sites and everything about the customer's online presence in a centralized location with the person I do freelance web development for. Right now we're using individual spreadsheets for each client in Dropbox, but it's getting a bit cumbersome to keep everything up-to-date so I was wondering if anyone has any other solutions they're using to track these sorts of things.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Here's an upvote or you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of [Ticketing System packages](https://www.capterra.com/sem-compare/help-desk-software?gclsrc=aw.ds&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsKXf8rrD4QIVNCCtBh2i9A_hEAAYBCAAEgJs0PD_BwE) that would allow you to maintain information via tickets. All would be centrally located, you could secure access, and even have alerts when something were changed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using git to track versions, branches, changes? Works fine for any ASCII-file, like code including HTML, CSS etc.

You can also enter binaries, BUT can‘t easily compare and find differences/changes with git alone.

Git and tracking systems often come together. Github is an example for that synthesis.